# php Send custom data to php web server and save it to file

Tags: php, logging, save, message

I know that when requesting a webpage, there is different ways of requesting it.  Get, Post, PUT, Patch, Delete and a few more.
But I wonder how I could send like a text file including multiple lines to a php web server, and get that server to catch the message and save it? I managed to do this with 1 line, and looked like this:

```
GET /SECRET-MESSAGE HTTP/1.1" 404 2306
```

But it only made me request a directory that doesn't exists and multiple lines would be problematic which makes this method really stupid.

I got inspired by this [video](https://youtu.be/4kX90HzA0FM?t=25m20s), where he shows the rubber ducky sending some kind of custom request to a php webserver. (No, I'm not gonna steal passwords) I'm not totally sure what type of request it does, or how it sends the data to the server.
The server then catches it by doing the following code:

```
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

But I simply doesn't get it to work.
When I look up the file, it says 0 bytes and doesn't include anything.

The code I'm using so far is this

```
$file = "log/" . date("m.d.y") . "/[" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "] " . date("H:i:s") . ".lll";
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

There is nothing wrong with permissions because I've tested with some other text and I've set all permission allowed to everyone: "0777"
Reason I want to do this, is to make a kind of a text saving cloud where I can send my notes to my server. If I remember something I want to write down, I could just send it to the server, and look it up later.

Is it anything I'm doing wrong here or not noticing?
Please help.

Comment: because `GET` requests don't have a "body", so there's NOTHING for `php://input` to read.

Comment: So what would I need to do? POST instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php://input` reads from the request body of a POST request

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: I got it working with a program called [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).
Write in your website/IP and send as a POST.
Then go to body, and choose RAW.
This way, you will be able to send raw data to the server, and it will therefore log the data.

This is only one way of many, and it was mainly to test if it was possible. Further on, I'll create a c# program which does excactly this in the correct way.

Thanks.